# adding elements to a query using multithreading

Tags: multithreading

Consider you are running simulations and each simulation writes results to a output.txt file. I want to run thousands of simulations using multithreading, while doing that even though if i use locking, unlocking, i was still having errors when multiple threads access to the file at the same time.

To solve this, I am going to add result texts to a query that stores them. That is, each thread will add result to this query instead of writing it to the output.txt file. And in the end, i'll take stored texts from query and write to output.txt

My question here is: whenever multiple threads are adding such items to a query, do you think an error might happen in the end, like, missing simulation ? I've come up to this question because whenever you increase single value by multithreads, that value will not be incremented as much as you want if you don't be careful. (i.e, in a multithreaded for loop, add +1 to previously declared int a for 1000 times; then in the end, a will not be 1000 (ofc this can be prevented by other things))

Comment: What language are you using? And what exactly do you mean by "query"?

Comment: Consider question in general, thats why i didn't tag any programming language and I don't expect a code as an answer. Query can be some data structure stores strings.